# OwlReady2: How to properly constrain the range of a DataProperty using ConstrainedDatatype

Tags: python, owlready

I am reading and following the owlready2 documentation, and I'm already at ConstrainedDatatype. The examples are:

```
ConstrainedDatatype(int, min_inclusive = 0, max_inclusive = 20)
ConstrainedDatatype(str, max_length = 100)
```

It's straightforward but there's no further example on how to use it in a context. So what I experimented using it in a DataProperty:

```
with onto:
    class Drug(Thing0: pass

    class x(DataProperty, FunctionalProperty):
        domain = [Drug]
        range = ConstrainedDatatype(str, max_length = 3)
```

Now to see if this is going to be properly implemented/written, I saved the owl file. And here's the snippet of the saved XML:

```
<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="#x">
  <rdf:type 
  rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#FunctionalProperty"/>
  <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#Drug"/>
  <rdfs:range>
    <rdfs:Datatype>
      <owl:onDatatype rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"/>
      <owl:withRestrictions>
        <rdf:Description>
          <rdf:first>
            <rdf:Description>
              <xsd:maxLength rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#nonNegativeInteger">3</xsd:maxLength>
            </rdf:Description>
          </rdf:first>
          <rdf:rest rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#nil"/>
        </rdf:Description>
      </owl:withRestrictions>
    </rdfs:Datatype>
  </rdfs:range>
</owl:DatatypeProperty>
```

Since the restriction has been written in the XML, I am now expecting that the "x" DataProperty of a Drug individual/instance will only accept string values with length <=3. To test this, I created an instance and set the value to a string with length greater than 3:

```
y = Drug()
y.x = "this is just an example"
```

This is where my confusion and question comes in... Since the string length I'm trying to store has length greater than 3, shouldn't this raise an exception/error? Or should I use the Imp() class and set a rule, for the datatype restriction to take effect during individual creation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Call the `sync_reasoner()` function, then `OwlReadyInconsistentOntologyError` should be raised.

Comment: Thanks a lot @StanislavKralin... i actually did that but HerniT reasoner has no datatype inference, so I used Pellet. However, my java version is jdk11 (macOS) and I am having a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter. Upon searching, it's caused by the JAXB APIs removed in Java 11. Any idea/experience on how to use Pellet using owlready2? Without downgrading to old versions of java? thanks again!